# How to efficiently find the newest shared commit of a branch while running server pre-receive hook?

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, nearest-neighbor

While the server pre-receive hook script is executing, suppose it receive a new branch called baz. Branch foo, qqaz and bar are existing branch. How to efficiently find the newest shared commit of baz(It's commit 3 in the example below. not commit 2 and 1)?

```
---0---1                   foo
        \
         \   8---9---10    qqaz
          \ /
           2---3---4       bar
                \
                 5
                  \
                   6---7   baz
```

Comment: I assume that by "shared" you mean reachable from any other branch?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes! that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this correctly in all cases is anywhere from "very tricky" to "impossible", because `git push` can receive requests to change, add, and/or multiple branch names all in one go.  That is, just because your receiving Git has branches named `foo`, `qqaz`, and `bar` identifying commits 1, 10, and 4 respectively *now* does not mean that this will be the case when the push finishes: it might contain a request to set `foo` to commit 0, to add a new commit 11 and set `qqaz` to point to that commit, to add several new commits past 4 and update `bar`, and so on.

If, however, you limit a `git push` to a single branch-name update—which you *can* do if you control the various hooks—the problem becomes considerably more tractable.  The trick is to recognize that the pre-receive hook itself runs *before any changes to any branch names are made*.  If `baz` is a *new branch name*, then there is no name yet, in all of the branch names in the repository, for commit 7.  (There might already be a tag name for any of these commits, or a tag name creation or update in the list of references to be updated by this push: be sure to consider these when designing your algorithm.)

If we make use of that, then:

- the `push` request has a line of the form `000...000 <hash-of-7> refs/heads/baz` in it, indicating that the branch name `baz` will be added, if this push is accepted;
- a `git rev-list <hash-of-7> --not --branches --topo-order` will list commits 7, 6, and 5, in that order;
- the parent of 5 is 3.

Should there be any merge commits in the new commit sequence, things get more complicated:

```
---0---1                   foo
        \
         \   8---9---10    qqaz
          \ /
           2---3---4       bar
            \   \
             ----5
                  \
                   6---7   baz
```

Here commit 5 is a merge, combining commits 2 and 3.  I'm not sure which commit(s) you want to find in this case.

In general, when you wish to examine the commit graph, `git rev-list` is the Git tool for doing so.  The `--branches` option tells it to use all branch names; `--tags` tells it to use all tag names; `--all` tells it to use all references.  A `--not` in the options causes subsequent references to be "negative references", as if you had listed, say, `^refs/heads/dev` to exclude branch `dev`.<sup>1</sup>  You can list particular patterns to include or exclude as well.  See [the `git rev-list` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) for details.

---

<sup>1</sup>A later `--not` cancels an earlier one, so that:

```
git rev-list HEAD --not br1 br2 br3 --not br4
```

means the same thing as:

```
git rev-list HEAD ^br1 ^br2 ^br3 br4
```

and in general the order of positive and negative references does not matter.

Comment: Oh.. I've learned so much detail from your post. Let's say I really limited to only push one branch at a time and using git rev-list. It seems like I have to list all the branches to get what I want. Is that correct?

Comment: git rev-list HEAD --not br1 br2 br3 --not br4
Actually this might work for my real question. Because I only want to validate new commit messages. I know the way we identify new messages is weird but this should cover most of our use case.

Comment: Ah, if you just want to find all new commits, `git rev-list <hashes> --not --all` does the trick, in a pre-receive hook. Get the list of hashes from all the to-be-created or to-be-updated branch names. This works because the `--not --all` subtracts away all existing reachable commits.

Comment: Amazing! It's more simple! It seems like replace git rev-list with git log also works. Problem solved thanks!!!!

Comment: `git log` and `git rev-list` are closely related ("sisters" or "brothers", more or less, built from the same C source files). The rev-list tool is the one most suited for getting hash IDs of specific commits. There's a (relatively minor, fortunately) problem with using `git log` in scripts: it has user-defined behavior based on the user's global configuration, and hence has cases where scripts break because the way it behaves for whoever wrote the script isn't the same as the way it behaves for some daemon process, for instance.

Comment: You can usually work around these `git log` issues with specific `-c` configuration switches, if they crop up at all. Just be aware that settings like `log.decorate` and pager settings *can* cause problems. Ideally there would be a `--porcelain` flag to `git log` to handle all of this, but there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

A bit complex, but should give the correct result :

```
git rev-list baz | grep -Ff <(git rev-list foo qqax bar) | head -1
```

If your shell does not understand the `<(...)` operator, you can use a temp file :

```
git rev-list foo qqax bar > /tmp/commit-list.txt
git rev-list baz | grep -Ff /tmp/commit-list.txt | head -1
```

---

Another way can be to successively take the `merge-base` of `baz` and the target branches, and keep the latest of those commits.

Comment: Depending on what the OP means by *latest*, keeping `--topo-order` out of the arguments to rev-list, or including it in them, could be important. :-)

Comment: @torek : yes, this answer assumes there is one single "fork point". In ambiguous cases, choosing between `--topo-order` or `--date-order` could indeed change the commit that gets chosen, but if I'm not mistaken, it doesn't give control on what path should be privileged to select that commit, does it ?

Comment: What the ordering option does is control where, in the priority queue that `git log` maintains, an as-yet-unvisited commit is inserted. The queue determines the order in which commits get visited and is handled as a "while (queue not empty) { pop head; visit; }" loop, with commits' parents getting inserted into the queue as needed (after commit limiting and parent rewriting).